# In WPF, Need Right Click Button Callback

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tool bar that I want normal left click to increase the zoom, and a right click of the same button to decrease the zoom.  However, I'm uncertain how to get a button callback for
a right click event to call my ZoomOut Function.  Note, I don't care about making this work on anything other than a desktop with a mouse.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="Zoom" 
         Content="Big Zoom Butten" 
         Click="Zoom_Left_Click" 
         ClickRight="Zoom_Right_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp5
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Zoom_Left_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
                messageBoxText: "Zoom In",
                caption: "Zoom",
                button: System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK,
                icon: System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Information
            );

        }
        private void Zoom_Right_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
                messageBoxText: "Zoom Out",
                caption: "Zoom",
                button: System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK,
                icon: System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Information
            );
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use a callback, instead create a property on your view model to hold the current zoom level, and call your ZoomOut or ZoomIn function from the property setter. Then you have the property implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and just bind the zoom level to whatever WPF property you need it for (or read it from the view model as needed).

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? You are calling the same code, just from the ViewModel instead of the form designer.... This is how WPF works. In WPF you are not supposed to handle click events and whatnot directly in the form, that belongs in the view model... Form designer is supposed to be minimal glue logic internal to the form itself.

Comment: Sorry then, I can't honestly show you how to do it wrong... But here's a hint: check the MouseButtonEventArgs...

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        // ZOOM OUT HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just `MouseRightButtonDown` or `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown`.

Comment: Could you explain this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272).